# Create condition while creating a subscription in CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

When creating a subscription in CDK, how can I make the subscription only if the particular condition is met? Eg. in cloud formation, it would be something like:

```
QueueSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Condition: IsNotDev
    Properties:
      Protocol: sqs
      TopicArn:
        topic-arn
      Endpoint:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - Queue
          - Arn
```

In cdk, I know how to Create the subscription as follows:

```
 new CfnSubscription(construct, “QueueSubscription”, CfnSubscriptionProps.builder()
        .topicArn(“arn of topic”)
        .region(sourceRegion)
        .protocol(“sqs”)
        .endpoint(queue.getArn())
        .build());
```

But how do I add the condition in here?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular `if` statement, i.e. create the resource conditionally:

```js
const isDev = /* your condition */
if (!isDev) {
    new CfnSubscription(construct, “QueueSubscription”, 
        CfnSubscriptionProps.builder()
            .topicArn(“arn of topic”)
            .region(sourceRegion)
            .protocol(“sqs”)
            .endpoint(queue.getArn())
            .build());
}
```